# Chart to show days grouped by weeks (X-axis) as well as values (Y-axis)

Tags: excel

I've got the following issue in Microsoft Excel 2010. Let's say I have a table with three columns: Week, Day, and Number:

```
Week       Day      Number
---------------------------
31     27/07/2014   15577
31     28/07/2014   17093
31     29/07/2014   16599
31     30/07/2014   16685
31     31/07/2014   16325
31     01/08/2014   15966
31     02/08/2014   15365
32     03/08/2014   12863
32     04/08/2014   16081
32     05/08/2014   13876
32     06/08/2014   16568
32     07/08/2014   11469
32     08/08/2014   17257
32     09/08/2014   14823
```

I need a Line Grafic to be created, that shows "Number" evolution in the Y axis, against "Day" in the Y axis. I can do that by selecting them and creating a graphic very easily, but...

The problem is: I need to unite each 7 week's days grouped by above the same week in the X axis, and I can't seem to find this option in the Graphic help.

I want something like this:

```
100000   ^              x         /       
50000    |             / \       /         
10000    |   x    x   /   \     /     
5000     |    \  / \ /     \   /    
100      |     x    x       \ /    
10       |                   x                  
          ----------------------------------------
           01/08     04/08  06/08  09/08    11/08 14/08             
            W31              W32                W33
```

Can someone please show me how could I do that?

Comment: I'm in a private network that does not let me post an image to Image hosting websites :/
I'll try it asap

Comment: Yes, something like uniting those days from each week with the week field like in my drawing, under the days but without repeating...

Answer (score 1):

Just merge cells of week colum (highlighted green in picture) and try to insert line chart after selecting data it will do what you require..see the screenshot below (from excel 2007) should work in 2010 and others...

[image]